# Captcha is not working in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, captcha, yii2-advanced-app

I have a project in Yii2 and in my contact form on localhost captcha is working fine but not working on online.

This is my captcha action.

```
'captcha' => [
     'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
     'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
],
```

And this is my UrlManager rule.

```
'<alias:captcha|index|contact>' => 'site/<alias>',
```

This is form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form']); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Enter Name']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Enter Email']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'subject')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Enter Subject']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'body')->textArea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
            'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
        ]) ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Captcha is working fine in localhost but not working on live. What's going wrong?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: can you show your requirements.php result from you server?

Comment: I mean please check and run your requirements.php file from yii on your server. Make sure the "GD PHP extension" and "ImageMagick PHP" are already passed.

Comment: @Undefined have you solved the problem ? If yes how?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski That was my server's error..  Some of extensions was not installed at that point.. Now its working fine...

Comment: @Undefined I also faced same problem yesterday. My `update` action also requires the captcha verification. The difference only a that I'm using googleReCaptcha (not *Yiis* own). I have added the `'required', 'on' => 'update'` to model rules but it's not solved my problem. I solved it by adding the captcha field to (also) `update.php` file. But, At this point what's your approach to solve this? Please help me to configure the correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make everything that is described in [manual](http://yii2-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/adding-captcha.html)
2. If you don't see captcha, check Yii2 requirments by typing in command line in the root directory of project:

   php requirements.php
3. If something is wrong - fix it. Pay attention that gd + freetype **OR** imagick must be installed. [watch "throws" row](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captcha.html#checkRequirements%28%29-detail)
4. If captcha is not showing again, check php files encoding. It must be utf-8 without BOM. Especially pay attention to *_local.php files that are in gitignore. Sometimes, they could be edited by ftp, with a help of text editors that add BOM by default. This item costs me 5 hours of work.

Comment: Another thing to check is if you are removing `site` from route using URL manager rules like this:
`'<alias:about|contact>' => 'site/<alias>',` that you have added the `captcha` action to it. Perhaps you did locally but have not uploaded that change.